# Validate the contents of textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <p>
        Search By: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
        @Html.RadioButton("searchByOption", "Load Id")<text>Load Id</text>
        @Html.RadioButton("searchByOption", "User Id")<text>User Id</text>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p> 
    }
```

I would like to validate the contents of the textbox in my index.cshtml file prior to running the view. If the textbox is blank and they pressed the search button can I easily reply with a message "Enter a value in the textbox prior to searching"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use model with Strongly typed view which will make job much easier, your model would look like:

```
public namespace YourNamespace.Models
    public class SearchModel
    {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a value in the textbox prior to searching")]        
       public string Term
       // other properties here
    }
}
```

Now in  View specify the model and use `TextBoxFor`, with that use `ValidationMessageFor` helper to show the error message applied on Model property in `Required` attribute:

```
@model YourNamespace.Models.SearchModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
<p>
    Search By: @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Term) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Term)
    @Html.RadioButton("searchByOption", "Load Id")<text>Load Id</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchByOption", "User Id")<text>User Id</text>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p> 
}
```

and in controller you would need to check Model State, if it is not valid send the model object back to view else perform the required business logic and database opertation:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{

   public ActionResult YourAction(SearchModel model)
   {

     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        // perform search here
     }
     else
     {
       return View(model); // send back model 
     }

   }

}
```

Please have a look at [following blogpost here](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/09/check-if-usernameemail-already.html) which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!